# Send selectInput value when input changed (without needing submit button) Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make it so that when I change my selectInput value it reactive value is passed automatically without needing to press a submit button.  Is this possible?

```
selectInput("variable1", "Choose ID:", vec)
```

The above requires a submit button to be clicked before the value is passed.

Comment: ?? This is the default behavior ("reactivity"), you don't need submit button.

Comment: All I had to do was remove the submit buttons...I didn't realize they were forcing the "non-reactivity" of the App. Thank you.